# Custom JSONDecoder for ID Task Result, ESRI Flex API

Tags: arcgis-flex-api

When the ESRI API decodes a response from the identify task, there is a few second lock in the Flash application which is due to the decoding of the results.

I have used chunk parsing algorithms in action script to prevent the UI from locking, and I would like to implement this for the ID task response decoding.

I assume the class I need to extend is the com.esri.serlization.jason.JSONDecoder class. Does anyone know how I can get that code so I can re-write it, and use this extended class to parse the results from the ID task? Or, if I use a third party JSON decoder and re-write it, how can I use this class to parse the results from the ID task?

Answer (score 1):

See http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/49513-Custom-JSONDecoder-for-ID-Task-Result for two solutions/workarounds.